# Do android PDF viewers convert the PDF into an image?

Tags: android, image, pdf

I am making an app and part of it will view PDF's. The pdf's are on a web server and downloaded to the app. I am trying to understand what happens when a viewer loads a pdf. If it is converted to an image then I would like to try converting the pdf to a png on the server and just using that copy to view in app as png is a lot less hassle to deal with.

The only reason I would not convert to png is if an android pdf viewer maintains the vector nature of the file as zooming is critical and I want a nice crisp image.

Comment: You would have to ask the author of the viewer in question how it is implemented. Or, you will need to test your PDF with various viewers to see whether or not they behave as you wish. Just because they convert the PDF into an image has nothing to do with zooming quality. I can create a vector renderer that sucks at zooming, and I can render a PDF to a gigapixel PNG (then subdivided into tiles and/or converted into more of a mipmap) that would handle zooming quite nicely.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can php's ImageMagick handle what you are describing? Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Well, you wouldn't want to do a high-res PDF->PNG conversion on the server, as that would massively balloon the amount of data you need to download. You were inquiring about Android PDF viewers, and I was commenting on Android PDF viewers.

Comment: I see, so you are saying I could figure out how to convert it directly in android.

Comment: You asked about how Android PDF viewers render PDFs. You implied that your concern was zooming, with a further implication that vector rendering was clearly superior with respect to zooming. While vector rendering *probably* is better, my point is that if you want to determine zooming quality, *test the zooming quality*, rather than worrying about how they get that quality. Your question did not get into *you* converting the PDFs into PNGs on the client. While that's probably possible, I would recommend that you evaluate existing solutions first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately someone is always going to convert the PDF to an image. Or better said to pixels because that is what you need to display on the tablet screen (or any screen that I know of). The question is who does the conversion, when it is done and how well and quickly it is done.

For a tablet viewer, the challenge is to do the conversion quickly enough not to bother the user with load times and that often goes at the price of quality. There are virtually no PDF viewing applications on either iOS or Android at this point that do a really good job at showing all intricacies of the PDF file format.

That being said, the quality is usually good enough and if the viewer is well implemented, zooming for a PDF file should be a no brainer. Zooming simply means for the application that the viewport (the part of the PDF page that is visible) is different, but it doesn't really change the algorithm used to convert the PDF page elements into pixels.

That is also the difference between *you* converting the PDF to an image on the server and *the app* converting it to pixels on the device. Your server likely has more calculation power (at least it might have :-)) but the application knows at which resolution it needs to convert to pixels and what part of the page it has to convert to pixels. And a good viewing application can use these details to adapt *how* it does the conversion to pixels. There are lots of optimisation algorithms that can be used to only render visible elements and take shortcuts based on knowing exactly what resolution will be used for rendering.

In short, yes, you can do the rendering on the server and feed an image to your viewer. But keep in mind that - especially while allowing the user to zoom - you'll get lots of data and probably poorer quality than when you let a good viewer handle things in PDF...